# How convert String to String array

Tags: vb.net, string

How convert a String like :

```
Dim myString = "TEST"
```

To String array, to have something like :

```
Dim myStringArray = new String() {"T","E","S","T"}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for a char array, if you always want each element to contain one character.

Comment: Could you try: `myStringArray.split('')`

Comment: @PhongVo That's not possible. You can't split without a delimiter.

Comment: @PhongVo Also, `'` starts a comment, so your code is basically just `myStringArray.split(`

Comment: Sorry mates, because I usually code in C# so I am not sure the syntax in the VB.NET but I think both C# and VB have same solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to do a test for the most efficient method. MarcinJuraszek's method, over 10,000,000 iterations, took ~4000ms on average. Fabian Bigler's method took ~3200ms on average.

The method below took ~1500ms on average.

```
Dim myStringArray(myString.Length - 1) As String
For count As Integer = 0 To myString.Length - 1
    myStringArray(count) = myString.Substring(count, 1)
Next
```

Also using the below takes ~1200ms on average.

```
Dim myStringArray(myString.Length - 1) As String
For count As Integer = 0 To myString.Length - 1
    myStringArray(count) = myString(count)
Next
```

Comment: +1 but in Vb.net, when you define the length of an array, the number you enter is the max index, not the number of items, so the first should be: `Dim myStringArray(myString.Length - 1) As String`

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the file:

```
Imports System.Linq
```

And then you can use:

```
Dim myStringArray = myString.Select(Function(c) CStr(c)).ToArray()
```

Comment: I have "expression expected" on 'Function(c)'.
I'm using VS2005, maybe its not compatible.

Comment: Linq is only available in .Net 3.5 and up.

Answer (score 1):

If you always use one element per item, I would suggest you to get a char array:

```
Dim myString as String = "TEST"
Dim myCharArray as Char() = myString.ToCharArray() '<= char array "T"c, "E"c, "S"c, "T"c
```

Access your chars as strings:

```
For each c as Char in MyCharArray
   c.ToString() '<= your String
Next
```

Or convert your char array to string array:

```
Dim strings as new List(Of String)
For each c as Char in MyCharArray
       strings.add(c.ToString())
Next
strings.ToArray()
```

Comment: Excellent, This exactly that I want to do

Comment: There's no need to convert to a character array first, strings implement IEnumerable(Of Char).  You can just use the for loop with the string without converting to a character array first.  See Steven Liekens answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: a string is in itself an array of `Char`. You can loop over a string like so:

```
For Each character As Char In "TEST"
    Console.WriteLine(character)
Next
```

Or by accessing the characters by their index:

```
For position As Integer = 0 To ("TEST".Length - 1)
    Console.WriteLine("TEST"(position))
Next
```

Output:

> ```
> T
> E
> S
> T
> ```

You generally don't need to call `ToCharArray()` unless you intend to pass the result on to a function that only takes char array inputs (e.g. `String.Split()`).

Also: creating an array of type string where each string is only 1 character is just silly.